# How to implement modal popup view in iPad? Like facebook screen using sharekit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4

Hi i want to implement ModalPopup view in iPad. How can i implement ? I do not know anything about that. Can anybody give me some guidelines? A small screen like facebook screen using sharekit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go through the below blog tutorial,sure will help you.

[Using the PopoverView in iPad App Development](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/using-popoverview-ipad-app-development)

Comment: Nice links. But i'm looking for popupmodal view. If you remember that how the facebook screen opens from iphone app.

Comment: @Devang : But in your question you specify popup for iPad Not in iPhone apps.. And for iPad the above links are more than enough.

Comment: @Jhailya : And You gave me popover. Its also useful but I want popUP modal view. If you remember that facebook screen opens up in your iphone app.

Comment: Actually, I'm also looking for any implemetation for popup. The main difference is that popover nowadays always has an arrow, but I don't need an arrow. It just doesn't make any sense, I just want to show custom dialog using my own ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Accepted answer about popovers is correct if you want a popover. But you may want just modal window, not the window with an arrow! Then this is solution.

To implement popup in your own ViewController, create a ViewController in your Storyboard then use a segue with the following properties:

[image]

This causes showing your View Controller modally. To change run-time size of your View Controller, check the following setting of the View Controller:

[image]

Another way to implement custom dialog is to use [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/). This is pretty flexible nowadays, but it's still pretty limited. if you want to use custom design and multiple elements, better to use custom UIViewController.

Hope it helps.