# iPhone : How to display popup view like controller with image in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to display small popup view (just like popup view in iPad but here I want in iPhone) in iPhone with image.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of your earlier question: [How to implement modal popup view in iPad? Like facebook screen using sharekit ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769035/how-to-implement-modal-popup-view-in-ipad-like-facebook-screen-using-sharekit)

Comment: @Josh: Hey I am asking for popover effect in iPhone with image including inside. Not for modalpresentview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@devang you would certainly appreciate this http://iosdevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-popover-api-for-iphone-wepopover.html

The other approach is what Mehul suggested. Do let us know if you come across something which corresponds to UIPopover in iPad.

Comment: Nice link. But it will allow only text not image. I want to display image.

Answer (score 4):

You can take UIView dynamically and then add UIImageView in this UIView just like this

```
    UIView *tmpView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XPosition, YPosition, Width, Height)];       
    UIImage *tmpImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageName.png"];
    UIImageView *tmpImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tmpImg.size.width, tmpImg.size.height)];
    tmpImgView.image = tmpImg;
    [self.view addSubview:tmpView];
```

Hope this will Work....

Comment: But it will not give same effect as Popoverview gives in iPad. I want same effect in iPhone !

Answer (score 0):

Collectionview Can be popUp on screen. Below is complete code for showing collectionview as popup and hiding the popup window

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate  {

    //let popView = UICollectionView.init(frame: CGRect(x:8,y:30,width:304,height:200))

    var demoCollectionView:UICollectionView? = nil;

    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.loadColorCollectionView()

    }

    func loadColorCollectionView() {
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)

        demoCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x:8,y:20,width:304,height:200), collectionViewLayout: layout)


        demoCollectionView?.dataSource = self
        demoCollectionView?.delegate = self
        demoCollectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        demoCollectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 200;
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath);

        if indexPath.row%2 == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
        }
        else{
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue;
        }
        return cell;
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView else { return }

        if indexPath.row%2 == 0 {
            statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
        }
        else{
            statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue;
        }
        self.demoCollectionView?.removeFromSuperview()

    }

    @IBAction func showMessage() {

        //popView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray;
        //self.view.addSubview(popView)


        self.view.addSubview(demoCollectionView!)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //self.popView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.demoCollectionView?.removeFromSuperview()


    }

}
```

I created a button in Viewcontroller and called showMessage() function on button click it will pop up a collectionview with colors. On select of color popup will disapear.